# Bootstrap Validation is not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to use BootstrapValidator plugin to validate my form but it isn't working. If I press "Connect"  button it just refreshes the page.

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/u1gUUn00 (I was having probems writing code here).

what's wrong in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not included jquery lib in your code. Add below code in  of html

```
<script src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It should be included before you call "bootstrapValidator.min.js" or any other JS.